# How to include HTML sidebar in an HTML page?

Tags: html, sidebar

I have written the sidebar of my page in an HTML file. I want to include the same sidebar in all my HTML pages. How can I include the sidebar HTML file into, say, my Dashboard.html file so that the sidebar will be visible?

If it is not possible, can you please provide alternate solutions?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file Maybe it will help you

Comment: Look into this tutorial, this may help you - http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp

Comment: @Arkej Thanks for the link. I had checked it out earlier, tried out the suggestions there. Didn't help.

Comment: @yashpandey Thanks for the link. Didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in angular js as shown save side bar in .html file

assume your side bar dashboard.html

```
<ul>
    <li><a> Home</a></li>
    <li><a> About</a></li>
    <li><a> Contact</a></li>
    <li><a> Careers</a></li>
</ul>
```

by using angular directive ngInclude

```
<div ng-include="'dashboard.html'"></div>
```

Comment: Tried this out. The sidebar didn't appear. But did not get any errors either. What might be the issue?

Comment: you need to include angularjs in index,html

Comment: you can check this link
http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_include

Comment: Yes, that I have done. I don't get what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

There several ways to do so. I recommend using JQuery:

Let's suppose you have the html code of your side bar in sidebar.html file.

Then, in any of the html files you want to include, you should create a div for containing it and load the sidbar.html content in it:

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- ...or whereever you have jquery stored -->
    <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#sidebar").load("sidebar.html"); 
    });
    </script> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
     <!-- other content here -->
     <div id="sidebar"></div>
     <!-- other content here -->
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: This suggestion is same as Vinod's. Please check my comment there.

Comment: Your syntax error issue with Thymeleaf is not related to html include technique. Double check carefully your code. Or share it with us so that we can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You are unable to include `HTML` page inside another `HTML` directly. But we can achieve this by using [Jquery Load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function. See the example,

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <script src="/path/to/jquery.js"></script> 
    <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#sidebar").load("sidebar.html"); 
    });
    </script> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
     <div id="sidebar"></div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: I'm using Thymeleaf in my page. Using this throws "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" for the line 
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en"> in the dashboard.html file.